# Galois extension generated by 2-torsion points

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve such that $E(\mathbb{Q})[2]$ is trivial. Hence image of the well known Galois representation $$\rho:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{Aut}(E[2])=\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$$
is not trivial. So the image is either $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ or $S_3$. On the hand, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta_{E}})$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(E[2])$. In particular if the discriminant of $\Delta_{E}$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}$, image of $\rho$ is definitely $S_3$: $2\mid \mathrm{deg}(\mathbb{Q}(E[2])/\mathbb{Q})$ and $(x,y)\in E[2]$ implies $y=0$, and $\mathbb{Q}(E[2])/\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}(x)/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree divisible by $3$. Summarizing the discussion, $\mathrm(im)(\rho)=S_3$ if $\Delta_E$ is not a square. Am I making the correct conclusion?

Comment: Seems ok. If $\Delta$ is a square then it is a cyclic group of order 3. The group of order 2 can't occur as it would not act transitively on 3 points. Note you question is just Galois theory of an irreducible polynomial $x^3+Ax+B$ of degree 3.